# Trying to use Entity Framework with asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to make EntityFramework work with ASP .NET MVC3 using this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Ok, I have my database, my .edmx model, model classes but one first thing I don't get is:
How does my DbContext derived class even know my .emdx model ? I don't fine where the "link" is created in this tutorial (maybe having  several thing with the same name "SchoolContext", for the context as for the connexionstring is confusing ...)

When I run what I got for now with the code:

```
    MMContext context = new MMContext();

    List<EntityUser> testList = (from u in context.Users
                                select u).ToList();
```

I get:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'EntityUser' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Users� is based on type �EntityUser� that has no keys defined.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: But this tutorial shows *Code-First* approach. You should not have an EDMX file at all. Or are you trying to "convert" the example to Database- or Model-First?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually looking for a Database first approx (well, I mean I created the model based on an existing DB). A good tutorial for that would help me.

Comment: Brief DB & Model First introduction (for EF >= 4.1) is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: I've just tried this but the ".tt" entries have no icons which looks weird dans their ".cs" files are just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Code-First approach, you have to define a Key in your Users class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

As mentioned from Kyle, if your ID field is not named "Id" you have to add the `[Key]` attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int u_Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually looking for a Database first approx (well, I mean I created the model based on an existing DB). A good tutorial for on would help me. Anyway, what in this code example does define the Id field as a key ? Because it's name Id ? Because I guessed that "Id" would be a name as any other.

Comment: @user code-first looks for an int property with a name of Id and designates that as the Key.  Other properties can be made keys by adding the [Key] attribute.

Comment: I have a int field called u_Id ... in the example I was trying to follow, he usually simple have his keys finishing with Id. How do I add the [Key] attibute in the C# code ? (including 'using' if required)

Comment: Kyle: Thanks, I should have mentioned that as well. User: I added the example. But you should not use prefixes in your DB Layout, I did that for a long time and it is simply useless.

Comment: Thank you for the example, good to know, although I'm actually using the DB/Model-First approach and I found what I was actually missing. (I can't mark this as the answer since it's not really the answer to my main question, and I can't mark it as "useful" because it says I don't have enough "reputation".)

Comment: No worries, that happens. But you should post your solution as answer and accept it (yes, thats possible) so the whole thing here is completed ;)